# connecting windows phone application to a website?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone, so if something looks weird in my question just ignore it :)

I want to make an application on windows phone , this app will save and retrieve data from a database on a server.

How can this be done in details ?

Here's my suggestion , i can make a website that takes GET variables and insert them into the database , Phone application will insert data by going to url "example.com?username=kareem"
But how can i get this data back ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to look at: http://watwp.codeplex.com/ that may at least give you a good idea of how it can be done if the server is in azure.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad.  You may want to read up on REST services... this is a way that you could both add and retrieve data.  Once you do that, look at the WebClient class in WP7.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the database created, you could create a wcf data service and expose whatever tables you like in your database via this service as an OData endpoint.
Once you have your service in place, add a service reference to it from the phone project. With that in place you'll be able to write LINQ queries against the service to make RESTful calls to the backend database to perform writes/reads to your database.
MSDN has some documentation that will take you through the whole process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521146(v=vs.92).aspx